# checked values for the SELECT: WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am trying to create a compare option between selected cars.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['compares'])) {
$id_nums = array($_POST['cBox']);
//$id_nums = array(1,6,12,18,24);
$id_nums1 = implode(", ", $id_nums);

$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_cars WHERE id in ($id_nums1)";
$cCars = mysql_query($query) or mysql_error();

while($car = mysql_fetch_array($cCars)) {
    echo $car['cartitle']."<br/>";
    echo $car['saleprice']."<br/>";
}
} else {
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM wp_cars";
$allcars = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());  `

while($car1 = mysql_fetch_array($allcars)) {
    echo "<input type='checkbox' value=".$car1['id']." name='cBox[]' />";
    echo $car1['cartitle']."<br/>";
    echo $car1['saleprice']."<br/>";
}

}
?>
```

How to pass the checkbox name(cBox[]) array based on checkboxes selection.

```
<form action="compares.php" method="post">
<button name="compares">Select Cars to Compare</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id_nums = array($_POST['cBox']);
```

`$_POST['cBox']` is already an array, you are making a 2d array. Doing

```
$id_nums1 = implode(", ", $_POST['cBox']);
```

would do what you want. Although it is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in & You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: What is the value of $_POST['cBox']? Do print_r($_POST['cBox']) and see what is there.

Answer (score 0):

**From your HTML part, send inputs this way:**

```
<form action="compares.php" method="post">
<?php foreach (mysql_fetch_array($allcars) as $car: ?>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $car['id']; ?>" name="cBox[]" />
    <?php echo $car['cartitle']; ?><br />
    <?php echo $car['saleprice']; ?><br />
<?php endforeach; ?>
</form>
```

**And in your PHP part, receive inputs this way:**

```
$id_nums = implode(",", $_POST['cBox']);
```

Comment: can i use while loop instead of foreach?

Comment: of course, but the way you have used [i.e. while ($var = func())] is not encouraged. :)